# How to properly solve const std::string& and const std::vector<string>& ambiguity?

Tags: c++, c++11, overloading

I have a function which I have an overload for like such:

```
void process(const std::string& text)
{
}

void process(const std::vector<std::string>& manyTexts)
{
}
```

And I call it like:

```
process({"hello", "hey"});
```

I would expect this to resolve to the second overload, however this is apparently ambiguous. To my surprise I found this to compile:

```
std::string text = {"hello", "hey"};
```

Where the variable only contains 'hello' which doesn't seem very useful nor intuitive.

With this I have two questions:

1. What is causing this to be a valid initialiser for an `std::string`?
2. Can this be worked around in some way which does not involve renaming the function or avoiding initialiser lists?

Comment: @bolov What is? The solution to the problem? Or the problem itself?

Comment: `std::string` has a constructor taking a pair of iterators. `const char*` is a valid iterator. Guess you are just lucky/unlucky to have exactly 2 strings in the initializer.

Comment: `{"hello"s, "hey"s}` is a valid option (if your compiler support it, see [operator "" s](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::string` has a constructor:

```
template< class InputIt >
basic_string( InputIt first, InputIt last, 
              const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

The call

```
std::string text = {"hello", "hey"};
```

resolves to that constructor. Even though syntactically the call resolves to a valid constructor, this will lead to undefined behavior at run time since `"hello"` and `"hey"` are unrelated strings.

The only way to make

```
process({"hello", "hey"});
```

to resolve to the second function is to make it explicit.

```
process(std::vector<std::string>{"hello", "hey"});
```

Comment: Oh I see, that makes sense. That's a bit unfortunate since it's a lot more verbose. But maybe not too much of a problem since it actually only shows up with 2 entries in the initialiser list, I just noticed. Thanks!

Comment: @Tobias, that's good. It will be a pain to have to use the explicit version in lots of places.

Comment: @Tobias, the strange thing is if you have more than two arguments, you won't need to explicit use of `std::vector<std::string>`.

Comment: You could also add a `process` overload that takes an initializer list.

Answer (score 1):

I'd back up.  Instead of fixing your problem, I'd expose a `process( std::experimental::span<const std::string> )` overload.

See [`std::experimental::array_view`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3851.pdf), a weaker version of which is easy to write.

Most of the work is in the long list of ctors you want:

```
template<class T>
struct span {
  T* b = nullptr;
  T* e = nullptr;
  T* begin() const { return b; }
  T* end() const { return e; }
  bool empty() const { return begin()==end(); }
  std::size_t size() const { return end()-begin(); }
  T& front() const { return *begin(); }
  T& back() const { return *std::prev(end()); }

  // extra useful things I have added in my version:
  span without_front(std::size_t N=1) const {
    return {begin()+(std::min)(size(), N), end()};
  }
  span without_back(std::size_t N=1) const {
    return {begin(), end()-(std::min)(size(), N)};
  }

  // ctors: span uses "pointer semantics":
  span()=default;
  span(span const&)=default;
  span& operator=(span const&)=default;
  ~span()=default;
  // useful ctors for making a span:
  span( T* s, T* f ):b(s), e(f) {}
  span( T* s, std::size_t len ):span(s, s+len) {}

  using non_const_T = std::remove_const_t<T>;

  template<class A>
  span( std::vector<T, A>& in ):span(in.data(), in.size()) {}
  template<class A>
  span( std::vector<non_const_T, A> const& in ):span(in.data(), in.size()) {}
  template<class Traits>
  span( std::string<T, Traits>& in ):span(in.data(), in.size()) {}
  template<class Traits>
  span( std::string<non_const_T, Traits> const& in ):span(in.data(), in.size()) {}
  template<std::size_t N>
  span( std::array<T, N>& in ):span(in.data(), in.size()) {}
  template<std::size_t N>
  span( std::array<non_const_T, N>const& in ):span(in.data(), in.size()) {}
  template<std::size_t N>
  span( T(&in)[N] ):span(in.data(), in.size()) {}
  span( std::initializer_list<non_const_T> in ):span(in.begin(), in.size()) {}
};
```

This gets rid of needless allocation in your `vector` implementation.

Which makes the single-string version pointless.

```
void process(span<const std::string> texts)
{
   for (const std::string& text:texts) {
     // process one element
   }
}
```

to call with a string, do a `process({"bob"})`.  For a string `s`, do `process({s})`.  To call with a vector v, do `process(v)`.

An industrial quality `span` would only have the `process(non_const_T)` style constructors for a `const T`, but I'm lazy.